# Google Maps pin links to a view controller

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

I used the Google Maps API in my app. I made the marker like this:

```
    //Marker
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.317160, 10.134287)
    marker.title = "Restaurant"
    marker.snippet = "Clickable Button"
    marker.map = mapview
```

I want to insert a clickable button or text which links me to a different view controller. I googled al lot to find a solution, but didn't found anything that works for me.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Google Map Delegate Methods.
Create new UIViewController as a popover which will be your info window of marker and present on below method

```
-(BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

create action of UIButton on your new ViewController

or you can also use below method for tapping on info window of marker.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

Comment: How can I do it in swift 3?